# How to create custom option programmatically while saving product in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

In magento, i want to create custom option while saving product.
Actually for specific category's product i want to create custom programmatically.
Please also let me know in which file i have to write script.

Thank you

Comment: anyone is there to help me ?  Thank you

Comment: Did anyone do this ?

Comment: Guys, i solved it my self.